# Is there a way to make your android app listen to home screen launcher double tap?

Tags: android, android-intent

I want my app to run in the background or have a broadcast receiver that listens to double tap on home screen launcher. Right now double tap on home screen launcher does nothing but if my app is running in onPause in the background, I want to be able to launch it when user double taps on home screen

Comment: The launcher application should register the event listener and this is clearly something you cannot do from an external app. [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4292809/launch-my-android-app-using-a-button-or-other-quick-guesture?rq=1) might be a possible duplicate.

Answer (score 3):

I dont think this is possible.
Your activty must be in foreground to get touchevents.
The only way to get information and start your app when its closed is by using broadcastreceivers.. and there is no broadcast for touchevents.
Maybe you can use a service to handle your problem.. 
take a look here:
[Creating a system overlay window (always on top)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4481226/creating-a-system-overlay-always-on-top-button-in-android)